# GIt overwrites the conflicts automatically

Tags: git

I'm trying to merge master into my branch(temp). When I do a diff with the 2 branches, I see a list of files being displayed.

git diff --name-only master temp

```
README.md    
service/broker/__init__.py
service/broker/client.py
service/enrichers/phraser.py
service/enrichers/org_id.py
service/helpers/__init__.py
service/models.py
```

Now, when I run the git merge commands, a merge conflict is displayed and see a list of files with auto merge and conflicts. Once I fix the commits, everything looks good.

One strange thing that I noticed is service/models.py is merged without any notification. It picks the file from my new branch automatically without any merge notification.

Why would this happen?

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit master
```

Comment: If you run `git status` after `git merge`, what state is `service/models.py` in?

Comment: I don't see the file being listed under "changes to be committed" or "unmerged paths"

Comment: I think you would need to provide more details, like the indidual git commands you execute, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Can we do a session where I can share my screen, its really difficult to understand for me as well..I see a file in git diff and want to be shown in git merge..

Comment: please provide also a trace of the relevant commits and ancestors, as well as the complete output of `git status` before you run `git merge --abort/continue` (i.e. when you are first prompted to solve your conflicts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I do a diff with the 2 branches [`master` and `temp`] ...

When you do that, you get a result of the comparison of the snapshots in the two branch tip commits.

That's not what `git merge` uses.

Without actually seeing your repository (or a clone of it) I can only guess what the commit graph looks like, but let's say it looks like this:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E--F--G   <-- temp
```

where each uppercase letter stands in for some actual commit hash.

When you run `git diff master temp` or `git diff temp master`, Git compares commits `D` and `G` (or `G` and `D`—the output of `git diff` is a series of instructions that, if followed, will produce the second, or right-hand-side, commit from the files found in the first, or left-hand-side, commit).

But when you run `git checkout master; git merge temp`, Git runs *two* `git diff`s:

- One compares commit `B` to commit `D`, to see what has changed in `master`.
- The other compares commit `B` to commit `G`, to see what has changed in `temp`.

Git now tries to *combine* these two sets of changes.  The combined changes are applied to the snapshot taken from commit `B`, the merge base.  Commit `B` is the obvious one to use because it's what both branches had in common: applying "our" changes (`B` vs `D` because we're on `master`) will get us back to `G`, and applying "their" changes (`B` vs `G` as found by the name `temp`) will include the stuff "they"—whoever they are—did, too.

Conflicts occur if and when whatever is updated in `B`-vs-`D` *clashes* with whatever is updated in `B`-vs-`G`.

You're actually running `git checkout temp; git merge master`.  This runs two diffs:

- one to find out what changed in `B` vs `G`, and
- one to find out what changed in `B` vs `D`.

This is the *same two sets of changes*, so the only thing that is different<sup>1</sup> is that now "their" changes are the `B`-vs-`D` side, and "our" changes are the `B`-vs-`G` side.  The combining will go equally well, or equally badly.  If "they" (`master`) made *no* changes to `service/models.py`, Git can just take *your* changes to `service/models.py` and put them into the base version, resulting in your version.<sup>2</sup>  So there's no conflict here.

Files that are changed in both versions may still have no conflict, depending on whether the changes were made to different regions within the files.  Git is not smart about this: it just says that the changes conflict if they touch the same lines, or if they abut (touch each other at the top or bottom).  So if you make an earlier-line change that invalidates something they use in a later-line, or vice versa, Git won't detect the problem.  It's up to you-the-user (and/or your tests) to find any such problems.

Despite this, Git's automatic merge tends to work really well most of the time.  When there *are* conflicts, Git leaves all three input files in the *index* (a.k.a. *staging area*) and writes the conflicted code to the work-tree copy of the file.  I like to set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` so that the conflicted area includes the lines from the merge base file, but that's a matter of taste.

---

<sup>1</sup>The other important difference, based which branch is the current branch when you run `git merge`, happens at the end, when you or Git make the final merge commit.  This merge commit has *two* parent hash IDs, instead of the usual one.  The *first* of these two is the commit that was the tip of the branch just a moment ago; the second is the "theirs" branch.  And of course, as always, the new commit advances the current branch—the one you're on, not the one you named in your `git merge` command.

<sup>2</sup>Git can short-circuit this by observing that base + only your changes = your version.  Likewise, for any file they changed that you didn't, base + their changes = their version.  If you and they made the *same* changes, Git can take either final version, and if no one made any changes at all, Git can take *any* version.